# UITableView ContentSize when using dynamic height on UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I've been searching for this for many hours but didn't find a way to make it.

I have a `UITableView` whose `UITableViewCells` use `AutomaticDimension` for Height:

```
tableView.RowHeight = UITableView.AutomaticDimension;
tableView.EstimatedRowHeight = 160f;
```

The problem is when I try to get tableView's `ContentSize`. It seems to be calculated based on `EstimatedRowHeight` instead of the current height of its rows. Suppose, if there are 10 Cells then ContentSize's returned value is 160x10.

Then my question is if there is a way to do this.

Any help will be really appreciated... I use Xamarin.iOS but Obj-C and Swift answers are obviously welcome :)

Comment: why do you need contentSize of tableView?

Comment: @ShehzadAli Well, because it is embedded in a ScrollView. I know it isn't recommended but it's quite a complex UI - It has an animated header like Twitter app so it's difficult to make it the header of the UITableView

Comment: What will you be doing after getting the content size. I think you are having different problem and you are trying to cater it in wrong way. Can you share your UI and share the more details what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: @ShehzadAli My UITableView has scrolling disabled, so after getting the ContentSize of the UITableView I'm trying to set the ScrollView's ContentSize based on that value

Comment: UITableView has default property of scrolling and it can dequeue cells based on datasource. I don't feel like you need to set scrollView's content size. Still if you want to continue this approach, you can set heightforrow against key(indexpath) in a dictionary and at the end you can sum these values. But i don't think so its good approach.

Comment: @Shehzad Ali, Maybe the tableview is on a page that also has a collection view above or below it like you might see with a news app. It's simpler to create a page with a collection and a table than to try to have a larger variety of cell types for the collection. Regardless, the content size of the table should be correct if someone tries to use it.

Comment: @DavidRector if it's a complex UI and as he mentioned he has disabled the scrolling on tableview and assigning the content size of tableView to scrollview. It basically means he is not using reusable cells as height of tableview will be equal to it's content size then I think instead of using tableview for this better idea will be creating a view and adding it's multiple instances to stack view.

Answer (score 13):

I think @Daniel J's answer only works because of the way the animation completion handler is scheduled - on the face of it, there is no guarantee the table reload will have happened before the animation completes.

I think a better solution is (in Swift, as that is what I was using):-

```
func reloadAndResizeTable() {

    self.tableView.reloadData()
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.tableHeightConstraint.constant = self.tableView.contentSize.height
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4) {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

I actually used the animation delay because of the effect I wanted, but it does also work with a duration of zero. I call this function every time I update the table contents and it animates in and resizes as necessary.

Answer (score 7):

I had a scenario where I needed to know the contentSize as well, to set the frame on a non-fullscreen tableView that had varying cell counts of varying heights. Then I'd adjust the tableView (via NSLayoutConstraint) to be the height of that content.

The following worked, though I feel it's a bit hacky:

Setup all code in 'viewDidLoad' 
Set the rowHeight to automatic 
Set the estimatedRowHeight to larger than I expected a cell to ever be (in this case, I didn't expect a cell to ever be taller than about 60pts, so set the estimated to 120) 
Wrap the tableView reload in an animation block, and then query the contentSize and take appropriate action in the completion block

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad]; 

    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 120.0;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0 animations:^{
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        self.tableViewHeight.constant = self.tableView.contentSize.height;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
self.coins = coins
tableView.reloadData()
view.layoutIfNeeded()
tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = tableView.contentSize.height
view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

worked without UITableViewAutomaticDimension and estimatedRowHeight. iOS 11

Answer (score 0):

```
tableView.reloadData()
view.layoutIfNeeded()
tableViewHeightConstraint.constant = tableView.contentSize.height
view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Before getting tablaview.contentSize.height
reload tableView
You need to update the view.